# Запуск *.sh файла из Django приложения

Tags: python, django, bash, flask, subprocess

Здравствуйте.

Есть задача запустить `bash` скрипт из `Django` приложения.

```
#! /bin/sh

clear

export PYTHONPATH=../../src:../../libs/MetOffer-1.3.2:.

python3 ../../src/programy/clients/facebook.py --config ./config.yaml --cformat yaml --logging ./logging.yaml
```

Но я получаю ошибку: `TERM environment variable not set.`

Вообще, целью этого скрипта, как видно из его содержания, является запуск `python` скрипта (`flask` приложение) и экспорт переменной.

Файл пытаюсь запускать так:

```
with open(os.path.join(dirname(str(BASE_DIR)), 'djangoprogramy/media/program-y/bots', project_name, '{}-rest.sh'.format(project_name)), 'rb') as file:
    script = file.read()
    rc = subprocess.call(script, shell=True)
```

Думал запускать сам `python` скрипт, при помощи `subprocess`, но не понимаю, как сделать `export`, и как использовать флаги.

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: У вас тут много всего в одном вопросе намешано: «как запустить долгую внешнюю команду из django» это одно, «откуда ошибка "TERM environment variable not set."» — другое, «как запустить Питон скрипт при помощи subprocess» третье (можно как отдельный вопрос задать). Почему вы пытаетесь из django приложения flask приложение запустить — заслуживает отдельного обсуждения. Похоже на [XY проблему](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/709/23044).  Обновите ваш вопрос, чтобы понять контекст, в котором вы flask приложение из django запускаете.

Comment: В чём у вас реальная задача: сделать запрос на другой сервис? (пример решения: requests)  Задачу в очередь поставить? (пример: celery, django-q) Выполнить короткую "systemctl start some-flask.service" команду? (в последнем случае можно и subprocess попробовать)

Comment: jfs, Смотрите, задача такая: Для каждого пользователя Django нужно запустить REST микросервис с определённым конфигом, который является Flask приложением.
У меня есть .sh файл, который запускает этот сервис. Но проблема в том, что из Django приложения, по сигналу, этот sh файл не запускается.

Comment: Так как для каждого пользователя используется разный конфиг, сделать один общий Django REST сервис не представляется возможным. Каждый REST сервис должен быть полностью автономным. Пользователь можно останавливать свой REST сервис, может перезагружать его, может вносить правки в конфиг, и этот сервис должен быть полностью изолирован от других REST сервисов.

Comment: кто у вас наблюдает, что сервис запустился, продолжает работать, то есть почему systemd/supervisord/etc не используете, чтобы запустить сервис? К примеру, `subprocess.check_call(['supervisord', 'start', project_name])`

Comment: jfs, спасибо за подсказку, сейчас буду проверять.

Comment: опечатка: имел в виду: `supervisorctl`  конечно, а не `supervisord`.

Answer (score 1):

Так пробовали?

```
import os
cmd = "sh ./script.sh"
os.system(cmd)
```

Если нужно читать результат выполнения, то

```
import subprocess
PIPE = subprocess.PIPE
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, close_fds=False)
con = p.stdout.read()
```

Comment: Почему вы думаете, что это хоть как-то лучше subprocess.call уже используемого в вопросе в данном случае?

Comment: @jfs Там человек написал что возникает ошибка, предложил другие варианты запуска попробовать, я же не говорю что это чем-то лучше!